# Different behaivour from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3

currently I'm working on a build script that includes some sub projects. The problem is that the build with eclipse does always fail. Below this sentences you can read the logout of Eclipse:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] CQ5 deployment Plugin ............................. SUCCESS [2.031s]
[INFO] Set up enviroment ................................. SUCCESS [0.000s]
[INFO] Hotfix packages for Communiqué .................... SUCCESS [0.406s]
[INFO] Archiva servlet ................................... SUCCESS [0.375s]
[INFO] Ldap Client ....................................... SUCCESS [0.422s]
[INFO] Hibernate ......................................... SUCCESS [7.719s]
[INFO] Main .............................................. SUCCESS [0.015s]
[INFO] Base .............................................. SUCCESS [0.000s]
[INFO] Core .............................................. FAILURE [1.578s]
[INFO] UI ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Commons ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Core .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] UI ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Internet .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Core .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] UI ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Infothek .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Core .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] UI ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.390s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 14 16:37:31 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.2:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project core: Execution generate-scr-scrdescriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.2:scr failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.2:scr: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/c:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/reporter/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/maven-scr-plugin/1.7.2/maven-scr-plugin-1.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/c:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/reporter/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.2/maven-archiver-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/c:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/reporter/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.4/plexus-utils-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/c:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/reporter/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/c:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/reporter/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/c:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/reporter/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.scr.generator/1.1.2/org.apache.felix.scr.generator-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/c:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/reporter/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/1.12/qdox-1.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/c:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/reporter/.m2/repository/asm/asm-all/3.1/asm-all-3.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>de.xxx.cq5.ldap:Ldap:1.0.0, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

If I run the build script in a dos prompt it will run in a successful result.

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.1 (Indigeo). I made sure that all sub projects connected to the same Java version. Even cleaning the workspace and running `mvn clean` does not help.
I'm really stuck, so I hope somebody can help me out?

Regards

Comment: What JDK/compiler version are you using in Eclipse?

Comment: @Dave I'm using jdk 1.6.0_16. Running 'java -version' in the dos prompt generates the output '1.6.0_16'

Comment: You might want to try deleting the `maven-scr-plugin` directory inside `.m2/repository/org/apache/felix` just to make sure the plugin is correct and not malfunctioning somehow. Otherwise, it's probably (as it says) a problem in one of your .class files. I'm not sure what would cause the scr plugin to dislike a version number but the documentation is right here: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin.html

Comment: @matt as I wrote, outside of Eclipse the build process ends successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An external consultant has schown me the solution.

The solution:
Mark the target project and select 'Properties'. Then select 'Java Build Path' and then choose the tab "Libraries'. There I could see that Eclipse used JRE 1.5.0_12. I selected it and pressed the button "Edit", so another menue did occure. There were three radio buttons ('Execution enviroment', 'Alternate JRE' and 'Workspace default JRE (jdk1.6.0_16)'. Default was the first option enabled. After enabling the third option my problem has beeing gone.

The extern consultant assumed that was an issue with the timepoint of installation of Eclipse. Then were was the above jre 1.5 defined as default runtime enviroment. Apparently Eclipse sees it as "default" version. Very strange...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use m2eclipse. If so, maybe you use the embedded Maven instance (see the m2eclipse preferences) and that is another version than the Maven instance you use outside Eclipse?

Comment: I cheked it and found out that I don't use the plugin 'm2eclipse'.  I'm using an embedded version that comes from file system. I also checked the enviroment variable and both settings points to the same version.

Comment: I've got an solution for my problem.